# How to send packets in scapy from a specific socket?

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to send some packet through `scapy` by creating a socket. I want to send the packets through the socket which I created. How can I accomplish this

here is some code which I tried

```
pkt = "\x00\x1c\x7fb\xb5\xfd\x00PV\xb8\x08\x9f\x08\x00E\x00\x000/t\x00\x00\x80\x11\x00\x00\n\xe7\xa0\xc6\n\xe7\x922\xd2\xb4\x05\xdc\x00\x1cH\xf4\t\x8d\x01\x00\x01\x01\x00\x10\xff\xff\xfe\xd4\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb2\x1a=\x0f"
Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)                   
Socket.bind(('',udp_sport))
S = Socket.connect_ex(("10.146.144.51",1803))    
Socket.settimeout(10)        
sendp(pkt,socket=S)
```

I have seen in `scapy` library that there is an option to use Socket in `sendp`. How can I use this to send? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StreamSocket` as a wrapper for your socket. See https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layers/tcp.html?highlight=streamsocket#using-the-kernel-s-tcp-stack

In your case:

```
ss=StreamSocket(s,Raw)
ss.send(...)
```

Note: in your example, you are using `sendp()`. This means a layer 2 packet. This won't work with the layer 3 socket that you have created: make sure the packet you are sending is L3.